# Mode coming different than seen in distribution plot

Tags: seaborn, distribution

I am trying to plot distribution of the values in my file. While the chart is looking fine, however the data looks negatively skewed and when i calculated skew it came as positive. I further analyzed data to see what is mean median mode to confirm the chart. And mode is not at the highest point of the distribution chart.

I am using

sns.distplot(AVG.loc[AVG['Month'] == 'May 2020','Asset Value Growth'],hist=True,label='May 2020')

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong over here ?

Comment: Without data it is hard to say. You write "I further analyzed data to see what is mean median mode" but don't show which functions you used. The mode of a list of values usually isn't meaningful when trying to tell something about the underlying statistics.

Comment: monthlygroup = AVG.groupby('Month')
mean = monthlygroup.aggregate({'Asset Value Growth':np.mean}).reset_index()                      AVG.loc[AVG['Month'] == 'May 2020','Asset Value Growth'].mode() what kind of plot is usually meaningful to see skewness of data